# Click in Selenium + Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

**I have a problem with click in Selenium, it doesn't click on the button. This is my code:**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import click
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://help.instagram.com/contact/723586364339719/")

submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_8"]')
submit_button.click()
```

**This is the HTML code:**

```html
<button value="1" class="_42ft _4jy0 _4jy4 _4jy1 selected _51sy" type="submit" id="u_0_8">Enviar</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with using explicit wait for the button:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='u_0_8']"))).click()
```

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```py
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_8"]')
submit_button.click()
```

Try this:

```py
driver.find_element_by_id("id='u_0_8']").click()
```

Comment: It doesnt work 
line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="id='u_0_8']"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)

Comment: Try print(driver.page_source), and check the html actually contains the element.

Comment: i think it actually contains it, no? 
view-source:https://help.instagram.com/contact/723586364339719/

Comment: You have to print it and check if it contains the same id or not.

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://help.instagram.com/contact/723586364339719/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://help.instagram.com/contact/723586364339719/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@value='1' and normalize-space()='Send']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: instagram_send_click]